# Can my laptop PC run Ubuntu?

Tags: system-requirements

I'm new here! I was wondering if my PC can run Ubuntu and I don't know how to check it...
My system is:
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz
RAM: 4GB (2,70GB AVAILABLE)
32 BITS

Can somebody help me pleaseee?? Thankssss

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand my system compared to others, I don't know which one is better :S

Comment: Better, how? "Better" is subjective until you define what it means. However, since your system is NOT a 32-bit system according to https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/53438/intel-core-i3-2350m-processor-3m-cache-2-30-ghz.html you may run a 64-bit Ubuntu or Ubuntu 'flavour' https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours  and therefore have a broader seclection of choices.

Comment: Welcome! You can be guided by the RAM. I think @user535733 link is outdated, it has 6 years. Ubuntu desktop works fine with 4gb ram, at least in my experience. Lighter flavours will be more than ok, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu budgie, Ubuntu mate.

Comment: Thank you very much :D

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize that the editings in the link are (sort of) up to date. @user535733

Comment: Why not try it before you install?   Installed systems run faster than 'live' systems, but it'll let you test on your own hardware - https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/try-ubuntu-before-you-install-it/14014   FYI:  My desktop is a decade old (before i series processors came out and will run all UBuntu's; but your system will be amd64 (64-bits I bet) as amd64 (called that because AMD created it, intel uses it too) became pretty common post 1999; early-mid 2000's intel atoms maybe 32bit (x86) an i3 will be x86_64/amd64)

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration should be OK, as the recommended minimum requirements are:

- 2 GHz dual core processor
- 4 GiB RAM

To be safe, you should try first Ubuntu with a live CD. If you're convinced then you can install it on your laptop.
If not, you may want to use a lightweight alternative, like Xubuntu or Lubuntu, which will definitely suitable to your config.